# How to use or re-package a package for Debian distribution?

Tags: package-management, debian

I want to use IRAF(http://iraf.noao.edu/) in package format and I hope the package keep maintained.

I found [iraf](https://packages.debian.org/source/buster/iraf) package which is packaged for Debian testing (buster).
I tried `sudo dpkg -i iraf_2.16.1%2b2018.03.10-2_amd64.deb` and succeeded to run `cl` by chaining the command `irafcl` in Ubuntu bionic.

1. How can I make this package keep maintained?
2. Should I make PPA for Ubuntu package to translate a Debian package?
3. I want to let others know the IRAF package since the original IRAF on NOAO is very difficult to install and upgrade. How can I help the users of IRAF?

Comment: Wow! Thank you for your information. Problem solved! I have tried on 16.04 (xenial) last week and I just upgrade to 18.04 today morning. That was the problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your information - IRAF is [packaged in Ubuntu since Bionic Beaver 18.04](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=iraf) LTS:

> Package iraf
>
> - bionic (18.04LTS) (science): Image Reduction and Analysis Facility [universe]
>     2.16.1+2018.03.10-2: amd64 arm64 armhf i386 ppc64el
> - cosmic (science): Image Reduction and Analysis Facility [universe]
>     2.16.1+2018.03.10-2: amd64 arm64 armhf i386 ppc64el

You may consider upgrade from your Ubuntu version.

Answer (score 1):

I am the maintainer of IRAF in Debian (and Ubuntu). To your third point: the best way to help here is to test the package and let us know about any problems you experience. Use the [Launchpad bug page](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/iraf) or the [github issues](https://github.com/olebole/iraf-v216) for it, or report it to the Debian bug system. Patches for improvements are also more than welcome.

We would also need someone who maintains backports to Ubuntu 16.04 and Debian Stretch.